# Duplicar mi AMI en AWS y apuntar a otro dominio

Tags: aws, ec2

He creado una AMI de una máquina EC2 de AWS y lanzado una nueva instancia utilizando la AMI creada.

La máquina original a partir de la cual se creó la AMI pertenecía al dominio midominio.com. Ahora bien, quiero que la nueva máquina levantada con la AMI apunte al nuevo dominio creado: qa.midominio.com.

Para ello he creado un nuevo registro en route53:

qa.midominio.com A ipDelaNuevaInstancia

Pero cuando accedo a qa.midominio.com me redirige a midominio.com

¿Alguna idea de qué más tengo que hacer?

Comment: Es probable que dentro del mismo código de esa instancia tengas que si está dentro de un subdominio, redireccione al dominio padre... porque como lo tienes debería funcionarte... Puedes también revisar las reglas del .htaccess a ver si hay alguna que redireccione.

Comment: Ensaya editar temporalmente el index.php (o en lo que sea que esté hecha tu pagina) para mostrar solo un mensaje sencillo, un "hola mundo" sin que se procese toda tu pagina... ahi verificaras si es la misma página la que redirecciona a otro lado (por ejemplo, algunas paginas de wordpress tienen  ciertas redirecciones en el mismo código de wordpress)... Como no se en que está hecha tu página no se que mas opciones darte. Saludos

Comment: está hecha en wordpress

Comment: he probado a modificar el htaccess pero sin éxito. Ahora me lleva a un 404

Comment: el contenido de mi .htaccess es: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule> @Pipe

Comment: Entonces el redireccionamiento debe estar dentro del mismo wordpress, en alguna configuración (Y ahi si no te puedo ayudar, porque no tengo mucho conocimiento de wordpress)